# ViewPager tabs and Drawer layout possible?

Tags: android

I am trying to do a tab layout with ViewPager and a navigation Drawer but without using any external library and for Android 4.0.3.
Surfing on the web and stackoverflow I didnt find any clear solutions. All of them workaround saying: not use tabs and drawer together, or implement your own tabs, or use an external library.

The Drawer is shown below the tabs:
http://i393.photobucket.com/albums/pp11/fmeneuhe/drawer2.png

The main layout:

```
enter code here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>


<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Any idea about how to overlap the tabs without using external libraries?
Thanks

Comment: You definetely can, I've done that in several projects. Do you know how to implement Tabs and Navigation Drawer separately? What's the problem by doing both at the same time?

Comment: BTW, I would use the compatibility library when working with de Action Bar, no matters if your minimum required API is 4.0.3, because there are some little differencies (and it will be more) in every API, and the compatibility library saves you from all that mess.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible. you have your drawer in the activity and the ViewPager inside of a fragment. It will just be a little awkward to use since the swipe gesture is overloaded to both swipe between views, and opening the drawer

Comment: I have it running, but when I open the drawer it does not overlaps the tabs, the drawer opens below the tabs. It's possible then to make the draer overlaps the tabs without external library? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying the same and finally I got it.

You get the source code here:
https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/DrawerWithTabsAndViewPager

Here is a little explanation about it:

1. The first level there is a Drawer, from the v4 support library
2. Inside the drawer, the first element is the tabHost, which I have set the width and the height of the content to 0.
3. Under the tabhost, there is the viewpager.

Once everything has been created, what I have done is create a listener for the tabhost and another one for the viewPager, so when the user click on any tab the view pager will set the current item, and viceversa.

Enjoy Coding!

P.d. I just created the gradle version of the project, which it will be continue improved.
https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/DrawerWithTabsAndViewPagerGradle

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.Try something like this, with fragments.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyContext" >

    <fragment
      ... go here (with viewpager)
    </fragment>


    <com.custom.SlidingMenuList
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: What is "com.custom.SlidingMenuList"? I want to do it without external or 3rd party libraries